# Position of character in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string :

```
var str = "u12345a45";//position is 7 here
```

now i want the position of 'a'(alphabet) in that string
similarly i have few more string like this:

```
var  str1 = "u1234567a45";//position is 9 here
var str2 = "u12345b4";//position of b is 7 here
var str3 = "u123c";//position of c is 5 here
var str4 = "u3d45";//position of d is 2 here
```

Now what i thought of doing is , just searching the string from last and know the occurrence of any alphabet in that strings for once.

Note:It might be any alphabet in a string like this:

```
var str5 = "u2233b45";//position of b is 6 here
var str6 = "u22333f45";//position of f is 7 here
```

any help will be appreciated .
thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As simple as

```
str.indexOf('a') + 1
```

for an arbitrary non-digit character it could be

```
str.match(/\D/).index + 1
```

for the last non-digit character followed by `0..inf` digit characters:

```
str.match(/\D\d*$/).index + 1
```

Comment: i might have any  alphabet , then how can i search it

Comment: @Irfan: provide an example for that

Comment: @zerkms: I was about to post that `match` solution. +1

Comment: thanks , i want to  search the alphabet from last just once , my string also have some alphabet initially .

Comment: @Irfan: provide an example for that as well (it's really hard to understand you sorry)

Answer (score 2):

just use indexOf method.

```
var str1 = "1234567a45";
alert(str1.indexOf("a") + 1); // alerts 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.

```
var pos1 = str1.indexOf('a'); // will equal 7
var pos2 = str2.indexOf('a'); // will equal 5
var pos3 = str3.indexOf('a'); // will equal 3
var pos4 = str4.indexOf('a'); // will equal 0
```

Comment: i dont have specifically a ,i might have different alphabets from (a-z) ,then hoo would i come to know the indexof(any alphabet) from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small Codesnippet that should solve your Problem.

```
var str1= "12345t45";
        var str1Length = str1.length;
        for(var a=0; a<str1Length ;a++){
            if(isNaN(str1.substring(a,a+1))){
                alert(str1.substring(a,a+1)+' at Position : '+(a+1));
            }
        }
```

I loope through the string and check if the actual position is a letter or a number. If it's a Letter i write him into the alert. In this Case the Alert says : 't' at Position : 6

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Please don't ever use the single letter `l` for a variable - in many font's it nearly or completely indistinguishable from the number `1`.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey : Oh, i don't notice that. Thanks for the advise! I'll change the code above.

Comment: "...Just an example..." - I would argue that makes it even more important that it be of the highest quality.  But I am anal like that.